# How to fetch only one kind of entities while using inheritance in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm

I have these two classes that implement single table inheritance strategy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
class A {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
class B extends A {
    ...
}
```

When I create a query to fetch all A entities, it brings me B entities as well. How to fetch only entities of type A?

Comment: you could make a generic abstract base class and make both A and B extend base.

Comment: is the descriminator column ("type") defined as a @Basic in the superclass? if it is, you can select by it maybe...

Comment: or if JPA2.0 is suppoted, you can also use *SELECT a FROM A a WHERE TYPE(a) = A*

Comment: We still use JPA 1. I stumbled across some suggestions by using something similar: `SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.class = "A"`. Turns out, I ended up using the solucion @guido suggested.

Comment: @guido, please, post an answer with your first comment and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a generic abstract base class and make both A and B extend base, like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="`type`")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
abstract class Base {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
class A extends Base {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
class B extends Base {
    ...
}
```

(note that SINGLE_TABLE is the default strategy so the annotation parameter could be omitted).

or if JPA2 were supported, you could just make use of:

```
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE TYPE(a) = A
```